# Laravel 9, vue 3, vite how to import global SCSS file and make it available for all components

Tags: laravel, sass, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to get rid of duplicated imports of my .scss files into each component in my laravel vue3 project. The issue i am having is that it doesn't apply the styles to the entire project.

here is how i am importing the scss file

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    fs: {
      // Allow serving files from one level up to the project root
      allow: ['..', '../../../'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
      refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          base: null,
          includeAbsolute: false,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
          @import "./resources/sass/app.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I did the same import in a pure vue3 library and it worked perfectly. on this laravel project to apply the styles i need to import the app.scss file in the main `app.js` file but that would trigger an issue of `"this file is already imported"` when compiling the code.

is there something special that laravel projects require for this kind of config.

Comment: Simply import it in your app.js : `import './sass/app.scss'` and clean up the vue config